# xslt writing to uncles of a context in a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input:

```
<element1>
    <elelment2/>
</element1>
```

and I'm grabbing a node set from a bunch of files and inserting as many elements as I find in the node set using:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />
<xsl:variable name="id" saxon:assignable="yes" select="0"/>

<xsl:variable name="views" select="collection('file:/C:/temp/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>    

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/element1/element2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$views/element3[somefilter]">             
            <element3 name="{@name}" xmi.id="{$id}"/>

           <saxon:assign name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$id+1"/></saxon:assign>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

this works great for getting the following:

```
<element1>
    <elelment2>
        <element3 name="view1" id="0"/>
        <element3 name="view2" id="1"/>
        <element3 name="view3" id="2"/>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

but what I'd like to do is use the same node set information to create parent elements as well so that the final output is:

```
<element1>
    <elelment2>
        <element3 name="view1" id="0"/>
        <element3 name="view2" id="1"/>
        <element3 name="view3" id="2"/>
    </element2>
    <element2 name="view1" id="0"/>
    <element2 name="view2" id="1"/>
    <element2 name="view3" id="2"/>
</element1>
```

thus, the generated id's and the names have to line up and are in different levels of the tree but are not ancestors or children of each other.

element2 and element3 are quite different so I'm possibly attempting to generate two node sets from the same data at the same time because of the id value and apply those node sets in different locations.

any insight greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're thinking of this the wrong way. In XSLT, you don't have random access to the result tree, so you can't create "uncles" of a node. You have to organize your processing according to the structure of the output, not the input. Look at the desired result tree, and think at each point "I now need to generate X in the output, what input do I need to access in order to achieve that?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite see where you creating "parent elements". Why don't you try something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="views" select="collection('file:/C:/temp/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>    

 <!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$views/element3">             
            <element2 name="{@name}" id="{position()}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$views/element3">             
            <element3 name="{@name}" xmi.id="{position()}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response!! indeed, not parents... is "cousins" the right word? I'm also sorry if its not evident, but element3 and element2 are quite different...is there a way to loop through the node set and generate two node sets to be used in different locations?

Comment: "Uncles" (siblings of parent) would seem appropriate here... I am afraid I didn't understand the latter part. What does it matter if "*element3 and element2 are quite different*"? ------ Oh, I see: you want different names. Hold on a momment.

Comment: as element2 and element3 are symbolic of more complex structures... in our for-each above we are only generating element3 with the given values but element2, while generated with the same inputs is quite different. hope this makes sense.

Comment: cool... ok, again sorry for not being more precise. I neglected to mention that I've provided a filter to the for-each (albeit the same one). is position guaranteed to return the same numbers for the same nodes? should I be attempting to assign the filtered node set to a new variable first?

Comment: "*is position guaranteed to return the same numbers for the same nodes?*" No. It will return the same numbers for the same nodes in the same context. As long as you're doing the same things in both cases of for-each, the positions will also be the same. Perhaps you should consider using the generate-id() function instead? That way it doesn't matter what you do, the id assigned to any node at input will remain with it throughout the process.

Comment: this is awesome.. it works. I've applied the filter to the node set making a new node set that I'm iterating over... until such time that I can examine the generate-id idea. but you've essentially nailed it. thanks again!!